# How to return json data in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

Good day. Help send the data in JSON format in JS Highcharts. There are two fields that are selected: Temperature and Humidity. On them should be based on the schedule. With one field everything worked as the only two added all died.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
/* SQL */
    /* Connect */
        try
        {
            $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my","root","");
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'Connection error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    /* /Connect */
    /* Query */
        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT temperature, humidity FROM weather WHERE date >= CURDATE()");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    /* /Query */
/* /SQL */
?>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'mychart',
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Values'
        }
    },
    series: [{}]
};

$.getJSON('../ajax/get_weather_day.php', function(data){
    options.series[0].name = "Temperature";
    options.series[0].data = data;
    options.series[1].name = "Humidity";
    options.series[1].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the result of both fields of your mysql table to both series.

```
options.series[0].data = data;
options.series[1].data = data;
```

You should split data and assign the right values to the right series (or you can make two ajax calls to get both seperately - check what's less expensive in your case).

By the way, data now holds the mysql result rows (value pairs) but highcharts expectes the values as numerical sequence.

See here:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series